# ReportViewer excel export set sheet names

Tags: webforms, reportviewer

I'm using the WebForms variant of the ReportViewer.

Let's say my report have records separated by two logical parts - CommonData and PersonData (they all have common field, say personId).
I've created the report to display one record on two pages - one with CommonData and one with PersonData.

When I click the export to Excel, the excel files contains one Sheet for eage page from the report. This result, in have one sheet for CommonData and the next sheet is for PersonData. The default labeling of the sheets is "ReporPerson1", "ReportPerson2". I want to change this naming with the following convention - "<> Common data" and the next one to be "<> Person data"

How can I do that? I found solutions setting the PageName property of the report, but this will set all sheets with this name!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found the solution in this thread

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2010/05/16/report-design-naming-excel-worksheets.aspx